# Python's select() delays reporting presence of output from subprocesses

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, subprocess, polling

I'm running this simple Python program to merge the output lines from two subprocesses:

```
import select
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
import sys

subprocs = [
    Popen(cmdline, stdout=PIPE) for cmdline in
    [['./repeat', 'abc'], ['./repeat', 'xyz']]
]
while True:
    rstreams, _, _ = select.select([p.stdout for p in subprocs], [], [])
    for stream in rstreams:
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(stream.readline())
```

… where `repeat` is a simple script that periodically generates output:

```
#!/bin/bash
while sleep 1 ; do echo $@ ; done
```

I'd like the output from the two subprocesses to be merged line-wise, so that the merged output contains lines of `abc` and `xyz` in any order, relayed in a timely fashion.  (Mixing data, such as `abxyzc`, is not desired.)

However, what I'm finding is that the Python program above produces no output for a very long time, or until I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

(I've tried changing `stream.readline()` to `stream.read(1)`, in case the problem is with `readline()` hanging, even though I don't want that kind of interleaving, but it didn't help.  Happens with Python 3.5.2 on Linux and Python 3.7.6 on macOS.)

Why is `select()` waiting, when the subprocesses are clearly generating output?

Comment: The stdout stream is line buffered by default. If readline hangs because there are few newlines, stdout will be delayed for the same reason, even if you use read(1). Can you tell us anything about the output of your programs? Most importantly, is there data actually line-separated? Do they output many lines, or rather at the same speed as you observe output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root reason is that you use `sys.stdout.buffer` which has a buffer internally, and therefore we could not see the result immediately.

We could explicitly flush the result after write. To put `sys.stdout.buffer.flush()` after `buffer.write()`. Or just use `print(stream.readline())` rather than `sys.stdout.buffer`.